# What is the Amazon OpenSearch equivalent for http.max_content_length and can I increase it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

In non-AWS-managed ElasticSearch, you can increase the value for [`http.max_content_length configuration`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) when you send data to the nodes to be indexed in batches to a value larger than the default 100MB.

This would be done in the `elasticsearch.yml` file.

In Amazon OpenSearch, you don't seem to have the option to modify the `opensearch.yml`(?) so how can you make a similar change when you encounter this issue?

Is it possible to increase the default 100MB limitation in Amazon OpenSearch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS sets a hard limit on the [maximum size of HTTP request payloads dependent on the instance type used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/limits.html#network-limits).

Currently, this is **either 10 MiB or 100 MiB** & **cannot be manually changed**.

AWS does not provide access to any `.yml` configs since the selling point of Amazon OpenSearch/ES is that it is managed for you & handles many configuration settings behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks Ermiya, I actually had the same page opened and I reviewed it earlier.
I found it hard to believe that AWS limits this change as it's quite a common use case. but thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @yobo No worries - I guess they haven't had many customers request for it which is why it's not been added in yet. If you need many more custom configs too, look to running Elasticsearch within AWS itself (but not managed) - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-voru33wi6xs7k?ref=_ptnr_elastic_fb_blog_esawsmp

Comment: This limit is pretty frustrating. We do have some requests where the size crosses 100 mb.

Comment: I'm using AWS Opensearch and I see that my requests are failing because the maximum limit is just 1 MB. How do I set it to AWS default

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change instance type to increase from 10MiB to 100MiB.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/limits.html#network-limits