# How to retrieve http.max_content_length from cluster settings in Elasticsearch on AWS

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

My task is to retrieve the max_content_length from cluster settings to control the size of the bulk request I am sending to AWS Elasticsearch.

I learned that I can do this by using the `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults` API.

When I connect to AWS Elasticsearch endpoint and invoke the GET cluster API, I am able to get a response but the body does not contain http.max_content_length.

I have tried running this API on my local installation of Elasticsearch, I can see `http.max_content_length` in the response body and I am able to extract the value I need.

I have also searched the AWS and Elasticsearch documentation/forums, but couldn't find any leads.

Is there something else I should do to get the max_content_length from the GET cluster settings API in AWS Elasticsearch? Or is there another way I can achieve what I need? Is the goal I'm trying to achieve feasible?

Other information: AWS is running Elasticsearch 7.17. I am using Java and Okhttp to send requests to Elasticsearch.

I don't need to update max_content_length and I just need to read it.

Edit: Just want to add I need to do this programatically, i.e. extract the max_content_length from json response of Elasticsearch API

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686523/4604579 ?

Comment: Hi @Val, I took a look at the link but sadly it does not have the information I need... I need to know how I can get the max_content_length in AWS Elasticsearch, not how I can change it.

Comment: in AWS it's hardcoded based on the instance type, the [first link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/limits.html#network-limits) in the answer provides you with the enforced content length

Comment: Thanks @Val, if I understand correctly in AWS the max_content_length is set depending on the instance type. However I forgot to indicate in my question that I need to get the max_content_length programatically... will just edit my post. But I'm unable to see in the AWS documentation how I can achieve what I need

Comment: it's a hardcoded lookup list that you can feed into your program, you don't need to retrieve this via an API

Comment: I'm not sure if it's good for us to do that. it's possible elasticsearch server is not always in the cloud, could be a local installation... Considering your suggestion, would you know if there a REST API in AWS elasticsearch that will allow to get the instance size?

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _nodes`? Not sure if it's even allowed, but worth a try